# Использование unicode в C

Tags: c, unicode, локаль

Как использовать unicode в C?​

Comment: Что значит "использовать"?

Comment: Хотелось бы иметь возможность присваивать чаровым переменным значения различных символов unicode и затем выводить в консоль. 

Стандартного набора ascii для создания текстовой игры не хватило. =(

Comment: `#include <wchar.h>` - и использовать функции оттуда вместо обычных (`strcmp() => wscmp()` и т.д.). Соответственно, переменные будут не `char[], char, char *`, а `wchar_t[], wchar_t, wchar_t *`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.
К сожалению уже второй вопрос подряд не нахожу кнопки плюса.

Comment: Сейчас ответом сделаю.

Comment: Но кнопка полюса так и не нашлась :)

Answer (score 2):

`#include <wchar.h>` и использовать функции оттуда вместо обычных: `strcmp() => wscmp()` и т.д.

Соответственно, переменные будут не

```
char a[]; char b; char * c;
```

а

```
wchar_t a[]; wchar_t b; wchar_t * c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    printf("Ура!");
}
```

Comment: При использовании русских символов вывод кракозябры. 
Если использовать английские - все в норме. 
Кодировка в редакторе стоит utf-8 без BOM

Comment: @Arseniy: Как подружить юникодные строки с консолью — это отдельная боль (особенно под Windows).

Comment: Нет ли каких нибудь альтернатив юникоду, которые можно просто подружить? 
Интересует вывод спец символов.

Comment: @Arseniy, в C/C++ работа с юникод это головная боль, если не использовать сторонние библиотеки, типа ICU/iconv. Поддержка в этих языках юникода никакая, можно считать её вообще нет.

Comment: В настройках консоли ещё нужно шрифт поменять на Lucida

Comment: Смена шрифта на lucida не помогла, пробовал и через setlocale, и через wchar_t с putwchar(); выводить, не хочет кушать нормально. 
putwchar на русские символы ругается.
Видимо придется временно отказаться от красивых иконок и вернутся к ним позже, с появлением опыта. 
Спасибо всем.